# Angular DOM event namespace

Tags: angularjs, events, dom

How do I namespace my DOM events in AngularJS?

I have some directives that bind mouse events on the Document:

```
$document.on('mousemove');
$document.on('mouseup');
```

After mouseup I do:

```
$document.off('mousemove');
$document.off('mouseup');
```

And then some other directives does not work, because events were destroyed.

In Angular's documentation for [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is written:

```
on() — Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData
```

Well, but I think I need [event namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to target which events to remove. So, what should I do?

Comment: How about removing specific handlers then?

Comment: OMG, I forgot about additional parameters in .off() method (facepalm). It works. Make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though jqLite doesn't support namespaces (yet, at least), you can always use `.off()` with a `handler` param, to specify which listener you should remove. For example:

```
function mouseMoveHandler() {
  // do some stuff
}
$document.on('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
// ... and later on
$document.off('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
```